# Почему не работает debug java? Ошибка: '127.0.0.1:62895', transport: 'socket'

Tags: java, отладка

у меня с не работает функция debug.ошибки:

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, appending to system class path failed
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:62895', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: Добавьте к тексту вопроса, пожалуйста, код. Очень сложно без него что-либо понять

Comment: Также не помешает добавить версию используемой IDE, шаги для воспроизведения, скриншот конфигурации дебага